# Converting to char to char[1] with double matrix variables

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

Hi I am using a variable:

```
char board[9][9] = {
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}, /* Game board */
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}
};
```

What I want to do is use my structs which look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int adjacent_mines;
    bool revealed;
    bool is_mine;
    char identifier[1];
} Tile;

struct GameState {
    Tile tiles[NUM_TILES_X][NUM_TILES_Y];
};
typedef struct GameState GameState;
```

So that I can then use the following function to attach a character to my `board[][]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TILES_X; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_TILES_Y; j++) {
        board[i][j] = tileInfo.tiles[i][j].identifier;
    }
}
```

Where the `tileInfo.tiles[i][j].identifier` has been set using this:

```
strcpy(tileInfo->tiles[x][y].identifier, "*");
```

The output I get on my console is that `incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [1]'` how can I solve this and can someone please explain what is happening? Sorry if its dumb, I am new to C and pointers

Comment: If you have `char identifier[1];` and do `strcpy(tileInfo->tiles[x][y].identifier, "*");` you actually *write out of bounds* of your one-element array, as `strcpy` copies a ***null-terminated*** string.

Comment: As for your problem, you have an array (`identifier`) and you want to get the first element of that array... Think about that for a little while.

Comment: why not simply use `char identifier;` and `tileInfo->tiles[x][y].identifier = '*';` ?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
board[i][j] = tileInfo.tiles[i][j].identifier;
```

to

```
board[i][j] = tileInfo.tiles[i][j].identifier[0];
```

identifier is a array of characters of size 1. And `board[i][j]` is a char

Or change the type for`identifier` to `char` since it size is 1

```
char identifier;
```

Answer (score 2):

Two related problems:

- You cannot do `strcpy(tileInfo->tiles[x][y].identifier, "*");` into a `char identifier[1];`, because you didn't allocate room for the null terminator. You would have to do `char identifier[2];` if you wish to use it as a string, rather than a single character.
- `board[i][j] = tileInfo.tiles[i][j].identifier;` doesn't work because `board[i][j]` is a single character but `identifier` is an array.

You need to make up your mind about what `identifier` is supposed to be - a single character or a string? Right now it is neither. The simplest is to just make it `char identifier;` without array notation and then replace `strcpy` with simple assignment `=`.